# Why do text editors have problems with long lines?

Tags: editor

If you copy the text I provided in the link below and paste it into a text editor (I tried several ones: `gedit`, `notepad`, `phpstorm`, but also command-line editors like `nano`) you will experience difficulties.

http://pastebin.com/5dqT7mFm

Here are a few I noticed during my tests:

- very strange text rendering effects
- text selection is not possible anymore
- heavy CPU consumption
- editors stop responding (sometimes they even crash)

I also noticed, that those problems will *not* occur, if I enable the `text-wrap` functionality in the respective text editor.

What I would like to know is, **why** text editors have this kind of problems with long lines? Is there a reasonable explanation for this behavior?

Comment: You can try writing your own text editor and see what it takes to write software without explicit limits on input parameters. It's not uncommon for software to target reasonable (in the eye of the developer) subset of expected input parameters. I.e. reasonably short lines, file small enough to fit in memory (or on disk), specific text encoding (or subset of supported encodings), specific user interface (text console, x11). If you get outside of supported (implicitly or explicitly) input parameters, things are going to get worse and would range from mildly annoying to outright broken.

Comment: Of course it is reasonable to limit the set of input parameters. Anyway, I would like to know **what** exactly makes text editors struggle with long lines.

Comment: Then you have to look at the source code of each *particular* editor as they all are likely to suffer for their own reasons.

Comment: @ArtemB I don't think the OP should be chastised for asking the reason behind something, specially when the question brings a great answer (and a good informative read, thanks @jussij).

Comment: @DavidG Wasn't meant to be. The question was very open-ended and I was trying (not very successfully) to suggest that the best way to figure out in general would be to try doing it yourself. jussij provided an excellent answer *specific* to Zeus editor based on his experience as the author of that editor, which kind of illustrates my point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I would like to know is, why text editors have this kind of problems with long lines? Is there a reasonable explanation for this behavior?

I'm the author of the Zeus IDE so I'll give my take on why this is the case.

One major reason is the existence of the tab character. Let me explain.

Because the text editor must assume the line might contain tab characters, the only way it can properly handle those tabs is to parse the line from left to right, always starting at the first character of the line.

To understand why, consider these two lines of code where ^ represents the tab character:

```
This is line one with no tables
This line has a ^ tab character
```

If the tab size is 8 this will need to be drawn like this:

```
This is line one with no tables
This line has a          tab character
```

If the tab size is 4 it will drawn like this:

```
This is line one with no tables
This line has a     tab character
```

**But the length of both those lines is exactly the same at 31 characters.**

So to draw the line correctly the editor had to parse the line left to right, always starting at the first character of the line.

Naturally for long lines this drawing can be slow.

Now consider this second case where the | character represents the cursor:

```
This is line one with no |tables
This line has a          tab character
```

In the case above the cursor is at index position 25 in the line, which also represents cursor position 25 on the screen (as the line contains no tabs).

Now let’s assume the user moves the cursor down one line as shown below:

```
This is line one with no tables
This line has a          |tab character
```

Now the cursor is still at cursor screen position 25 but because of the 8 character tab that represents the index 18 location for that line.

To figure this out the editor needed to run a calculation on the line checking for tabs along the way and once again for long lines this takes time.

These are just two examples of the index to cursor, cursor to index mappings that need to be done by the editor.

Those same calculations will also be needed for keyboard events, mouse clicks, text marking, text cut/copy and paste etc etc.

> I also noticed, that those problems will not occur, if I enable the text-wrap functionality in the respective text editor.

When you turn on text-wrap you have effectively taken one long line and made it into many shorter lines and that in turn speeds up the tab calculations mentioned earlier.

PS: Zeus did handle your 286,721 character line, but like most editors it does not respond well to a file with that length of line.